# How easy or tough is Phone-gap for developing mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Presently i am working on ios as well as on android so same app i need to develop for both of them one after the other..

Got to know about Phone-Gap..Did you have tried it..How is it for developing apps simultaneously and in much lesser time for both the platform…Is it easy or complex or it takes time to learn...

Comment: Note: people might downvote you because your question is too board for the standards of SO. Usually we expect more concrete questions here.

Comment: But the user should understand that he is new user.

Comment: Eh, people are generally quite intolerant with new users here... even if it has its explanation (some new users are extremely arrogant and demanding)

Comment: with due respect to all the experienced people i just want to say that if you think from a new user perspective it's not a boring question…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No mak,Its easy to develop native apps from phonegap actually you have to create write code only for one time and it would work for each platform that phonegap support just after doing some settings.There are some url which have great information.

For [Android](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android).

For [iOS](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS).

There is a link of the [Phonegap-Beginners-Guide(pdf)](http://lecturer.eepis-its.edu/~yuliana/Android/Buku/PhoneGap-Beginners-Guide.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

Once you set up the SDK for PhoneGap (note: currently it is called Cordova), starting developing with it is very fast. Basically all you need is some HTML(5) and JavaScript knowledge. Note however that PhoneGap as it is, is only a framework to embed your HTML+CSS+JS applications into the native framework, plus it gives you access to platform features that are otherwise unavailable from JavaScript (camera, accelerometer, etc) in a cross-platform way. If you know web client technologies, you will find it very easy to start working with it.

The backside of this approach is that you don't have direct access to native UI widgets, screen transitions and animations, to have the same look-and-feel like native apps. For this you'll have to install some other JavaScript UI frameworks like jQuery Mobile, iScroll, etc. It might take some time to configure these frameworks to work together and with PhoneGap, but it well worth the effort.

Anyhow, it depends on your app's needs. Because of the limitations of the technologies above (in the means of CPU, memory handling, native look-and-feel, limited access to native technologies), I feel that this approach is appropriate only for certain type of applications, most likely for thick clients behind a bunch of web services. They are also excellent for fast prototyping of UIs. If you need something more sophisticated, you better go for native development.

Comment: Maybe an other add: Dont think you will not have device specific code in you app with PhoneGap. You have to create a project for each device (see tutorials and PhoneGap help) and maybe you also have to do some specific things there (chaning the start page, using push services and so on). Also in HTML/Javascript there are sometimes special device handlings needed... specialy when you use frameworks like jQueryMobile